# Is there a way to empty the recycler bin for all users in windows 2003?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2003

I'm trying to free up some space and wondering if the administrator has the capability to empty the recycler bin for all users on the server?

Deleting the d:\recycler folder doesn't seem to be an option.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried deleting everything inside d:\recycler?

Comment: It doesn't list the files in explorer and deleting the recylcer folder says "Access is denied"

Comment: Don't delete the folder itself, just the contents

Comment: Do you know of a way to get the files to be listed so I can delete them?

Comment: Tools->Folder Options->View->"Show operating system files" or something to that effect, assuming you have full admin rights.

Comment: Or just delete from a command prompt: `del d:\recycler\*`

Comment: @phoebus - the trick was to go to Tool->Folder Options->View->uncheck "Hide protected operating system files". Once I did that I was able to delete them all except for the current users folder, then empty the trash can and bingo, freed up all the space. Thanks for everyone help.